# How do I copy/paste table data into different cells based on drop down?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Example: I have two 3x6 tables named "Apples" and "Oranges" with different data among them. I want Excel to populate empty cells of my choosing, say cells A1:F6, based on what the user picks from the drop down list.

So if I select "Apples" from the list, cells A1:F6 should show data from the Apples table. I made a nested-if statement, but since there are a lot of tables, I was wondering if I can shorten this formula somehow or maybe there's a different approach.

Another example: Say I want cell A1 to pull the first column & row data of a particular table, I would use the formula: =IF($F$1="Apples",C10,IF($F$1="Oranges",C20,0)).

- made ton of edits after comment for clarification. I hope I was clearer.

Comment: (1) If you’re talking about actually *filling in* cells, you may need VBA instead of formulas.  But maybe I don’t understand what you want.  (2) It would help in multiple ways if you would give an example of a formula that you think you could use (for two tables).  Bonus points if you can demonstrate that you have researched ways to generalize / scale that to a larger number.

Comment: To clarify, I just want a formula/VBA to copy data from a chosen table and paste that data into designated cells of my choosing. 

For example, I have a drop down box that a user can choose from: apples, oranges, and bananas. Based on what the user picks from that list, I want particular empty cells to fill with the data from the table the user picks. 

My formula for two tables for ONE cell (A2): IF($C$5="Apples",E10,IF($C$5="Oranges",E20,0)).

Now the issue is if there are like 10 tables. I looked at Index function, but not sure how it can help me on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest you a method which Filters records from Source Table based on the Drop Down Value.

**Please note,** *I've taken single Table instead of TWO which has data of ALL FRUITS. Since to Filer data form APPLE & ORANGE Tables on Drop down Value can be easily achieved by ADVANCE FILTER. And, if you feel you can apply this method to both Tables also.*

Check the Screen Shot:
[image]

**How to do:**

1. In Cell D2 of Helper Column1 enter this formula and fill down: `=ROWS($A$2:A2)`.
2. In Cell E2 of Helper Column2 enter this formula and fill down:
   `=IF(A2=$H$2,D2,"")`.
3. In Cell F2 of Helper Column3 enter this formula and fill down:
   `=IFERROR(SMALL($E$2:$E$10,D2),"")`.
4. In Cell H2 create the Drop Down list & add Fruits name Apple,
   Orange, Banana.
5. In J2 enter this formula & fill Right then Down.   `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$C$10,$F2,COLUMNS($J$2:J2)),"")`
6. Now start clicking the Drop Down, Excel will Filter & display
   related data in RESULT area, as shown in Screen Shot.

**N.B.** *You can adjust the data Range as you need.*

Comment: I'm late to this, but I definitely using this method. The filtering was easy for me to understand and thank you for the screenshot!!